# Автоматический переход из фрейма

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
location="page.php" 
</script>
```

Имеем обычный скрипт, который сразу прыгает по нужной ссылке. Ненужно грузить куда то в боди/мету, и прочее код.

Можно ли сделать так, что если данный скрипт работает внутри iframe, то нужная страница будет открываться не внутри фрейма, а в основном окне

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так?

```
top.location.href = "http://www.ya.ru"
```

Comment: @AlexWindHope, извини, акцепт снял. все же есть способ

Comment: @mixalef - все-же я не правильно понял вопрос, поэтому - никаких проблем, зато товарищу @lampa настроение поднял, пусть порадуется человек

Comment: @AlexWindHope товарисч лампа очень любит радоваться вашим неудачам, которые стоит списывать всё-таки на непрофессионализм, чем на непонимание вопроса :-)

Comment: @lampa есть такие мудрые слова - не судите и несудимы будете, подумайте об этом

Comment: @AlexWindHope да я просто злопамятный дохрена, что вы :-) А свои аксиомы оставьте при себе. И сердца у вас нет, и души нет, и спора нет. А равновесие и есть неумелость ваша и ошибки ваши и невнимательность ваша, также как и "проблема не ваша, не ваша и забота её решать". Алсо, покой и сытость для ваш лучше, чем спасение утопающего. Ведь спасение утопающих - дело рук самих утопающих? Так почему же тогда вы сидите на данном форуме и помогаете людям?